Issues connecting odbc in newest R Studio update
I recently updated R Studio and odbc/dbi seems to be broken. Running packageVersion("odbc") I see:
[1] ‘1.5.0’ Warning message: package ‘odbc’ was built under R version 4.4.1

My current version of R studio is 2024.04.0
Here's my basic code:
#Connect to data on SQL developer (oracle)
cj_db <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "my_database", UID='my_name', PWD = 'my_password')

#Process data
arrest_data <- tbl(cj_db, sql("select *
from my_database
"
))

Which has always worked in the past. Now I get an error:
Error in UseMethod("odbcListObjects") : 
  no applicable method for 'odbcListObjects' applied to an object of class "Oracle"

I've tried using (odbc::dbConnect) and I've also tried the solution listed here:
rstudio dbi odbc connect Driver for SQL Server
devtools::install_github("r-dbi/odbc")

I get a warning: Warning: package ‘odbc’ is in use and will not be installed
And it doesn't work. I still get the same error. And I've tried re-starting.  No luck. I wish updating R Studio didn't break all my scripts, but here we are.

package ‘odbc’ is in use and will not be installed indicates that you'll need to restart your R session before installing the dev version with devtools::install_github("r-dbi/odbc").
After doing so, could you print the output of packageVersion("odbc")? What operating system are you on and which Oracle driver are you using?

Thanks Simon. Here's what happens when I print output of packageVersion("odbc"): [1] ‘1.5.0’
Warning message:
package ‘odbc’ was built under R version 4.4.1

I've re-started the R Session.. I don't know why everything broke with the R studio update.. any suggestions would be much appreciated...

Drivers I'm using is: ODBC Driver 13 for SQL server as well as Oracle in OraClient12.  Operating system: Windows 10

I wonder if you could have a package conflict with dbConnect. Have you tried specifying the package you are using (odbc::dbConnect)? see additional package options at https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbConnect.html

@SusanSwitzer yes I have tried adding odbc:: prior to the dbConnect call

I am running R 4.4.1 and I just tested my Oracle connection.  No problems.  Can you do a print(cj_db)?  I also recommend testing the DSN you're using in the Windows odbc control panel.

What is you R version? Did you try to upgrade to 4.4.1?
